# Rest Webservice in Controller or Service Layer?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, cdi

While developing a REST based web service in a JEE 6 web application, containing JSF 2.0, CDI and EJB 3, does it make sense to combine Controller Class (normally annotated with `@RequestScoped`) with Rest Service Definition `@Path`?

Or, should it inside it's own *RestService class definition?

The project that I am currently working follows the below architecture as the requirement is to have REST services cater to JSF Clients, Direct accesses from other technologies.

JSF --> Controller Method (calls using Rest Client)--> Rest Service --> Stateless Business Service --> DAO (Also stateless)

If we were to combine Controller and Rest service (annotating methods with @Path), JSF client would directly call Controller method, and any other client directly invoke the REST service via URL or REST Client.

This would also permit us to take out REST Client code invoking REST Service from Controller.

Thanks for your time in looking into this.

Comment: This question is highly opinionated.  In my case, I simply use the rest endpoints as just endpoints which call a separate business logic layer, but there is no definitive answer.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but my question was would it make sense to have the REST Service end points defined as methods of Controller (use both @Path and @RequestScoped)? Is eliminating a REST client call between Controller and Rest Service worth when compared to separation of responsibilities between Controller and Rest Service classes.

Comment: Rule of thumb: it's not generally good form to "combine" anything in programming